# Send Alert when PC is Offline

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-monitoring, alert, system-monitoring

I'm simplifying/generalizing the scenario here. I am looking for a way to receive alerts if my Windows 10 desktop PC goes offline for any reason. The PC is on a private network / behind a firewall so I cannot use uptime monitoring services like pingdom / uptimerobot.

My only requirement is to be alerted if the PC is offline (or has been offline for the last 5 mins or so..), I probably can find free a server monitoring solution (RMM) in which I have to install an agent on the desktop and the RMM will alert me if the agent is offline.

But, 1) for such a simple requirement wouldn't that be overkill? And end up taking too much desktop resources on monitoring other stuff which I actually don't want to monitor?

2) what are some of the currently available lightweight products (preferably with some sort of a free offering) that will help me achieve the same? (note: I don't want install second PC within the same lan then monitor the the windows PC from there. Let's assume there is just only 1 PC on the LAN and I need to somehow be notified if it's offline, However I don't mind using a external server / service to get this task fulfilled.)

3) perhaps it might be possible to create a simple scripting solution for this. Have a small instance running on AWS, and then have the Windows PC send some sort of a keep alive ping to the AWS instance. If the AWS instance script doesn't receive the keep alive signal for X minutes, then it could send out a tweet / email / pushover notification or something of that sort? Is there any such simple script or online service I could use to have this implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is, the PC I want to check lies behind a natted environment for which the public IP is dynamic. And I cannot put another PC within the same lan to monitor. Thus the PC should have some kind of a call home script running and letting an external server know that it's alive. If no call home happen for a while, then the external server can trigger the alert. If you have any script that can achieve this requirement, then I'd be very happy to use it.

Comment: Well, I think I bumped into 2 solutions that would work.

First being, 
https://www.opsgenie.com/heartbeats

and another node.js solution,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/heartbeat-server

Both of these simplifies the task.

There is also a free offering by Anturis in which an agent has to be installed and it will alert in the event there is no response from the agent. 

I'd probably try out all 3 of these solutions and settle with one.